# How std::enable_shared_from_this::shared_from_this works

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I just cannot understand how `std::enable_shared_from_this::shared_from_this` returns a shared pointer that shared ownership with existing pointer. In other words you do [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this):

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> getFoo() { return shared_from_this(); }
```

So when you call `getFoo` how does exactly it get what is the other `shared_ptr` to share the ownership with and not to create a separate `shared_ptr` that owns the same `this`.

I need to understand this to be able to understand how to create shared_ptr from some object that all increase the same ref count and not initialize separate `shared_ptr`s.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this Have a look at the notes

Comment: I have seen the Notes that describe the common implementation. Before that, also I have looked at the source code too. But could not understand how this `weak_ptr` is being initialized when first shared_ptr is bing created outside of the class. A class cannot know that we have encapsulated it's pointer in some `shared_ptr`.

Comment: You should also have a look at the source of `std::shared_ptr`. The note clearly specifies that there is code there do detect the presence of `std::enable_shared_from_this` as a base class.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`enable_shared_from_this<T>` has a `weak_ptr<T>` data member. The `shared_ptr<T>` constructor can detect if `T` is derived from `enable_shared_from_this<T>`. If it is, the `shared_ptr<T>` constructor will assign `*this` (which is the `shared_ptr<T>`) to the `weak_ptr` data member in `enable_shared_from_this<T>`. `shared_from_this()` can then create a `shared_ptr<T>` from the `weak_ptr<T>`.

Example of a possible implementation:

```
template<class D>
class enable_shared_from_this {
protected:
    constexpr enable_shared_from_this() { }
    enable_shared_from_this(enable_shared_from_this const&) { }
    enable_shared_from_this& operator=(enable_shared_from_this const&) {
        return *this;
    }

public:
    shared_ptr<T> shared_from_this() { return self_.lock(); }
    shared_ptr<T const> shared_from_this() const { return self_.lock(); }

private:
    weak_ptr<D> self_;

    friend shared_ptr<D>;
};

template<typename T>
shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(T* ptr) {
    // ...
    // Code that creates control block goes here.
    // ...

    // NOTE: This if check is pseudo-code. Won't compile. There's a few
    // issues not being taken in to account that would make this example
    // rather noisy.
    if (is_base_of<enable_shared_from_this<T>, T>::value) {
        enable_shared_from_this<T>& base = *ptr;
        base.self_ = *this;
    }
}
```

Comment: How `shared_ptr` has access to `weak_ptr` member (I guess it is private) of  `enable_shared_from_this`.

Comment: @Narek it's probably a `friend`.

Comment: In C++17, you can make the `if` check (which is currently *pseudo-code*) compilable by using compile-time branch as:  `if constexpr( ... ) { ... }`

Comment: Why is it valid to use the template class `enable_shared_from_this` in the copy constructor & assignment without specifying the type argument `D`?

Comment: @MatějKripner because it is in class template body. See Current instantiation in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name

Comment: @Simple *The shared_ptr<T> constructor can detect if T is derived from enable_shared_from_this<T>*.How to understand that in the right way? Do you mean not all derived classes can detect itself  is derived from a base class?

Comment: I think there is a typo. It should read  shared_ptr<D> shared_from_this() { return self_.lock(); } and not  shared_ptr<T> shared_from_this() { return self_.lock(); }